# How to download a HTTP resource to a file with Akka Streams and HTTP?

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

Over the past few days I have been trying to figure out the best way to download a HTTP resource to a file using Akka Streams and HTTP.

Initially I started with the [Future-Based Variant](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.2/scala/http/client-side/request-level.html#Future-Based_Variant) and that looked something like this:

```
def downloadViaFutures(uri: Uri, file: File): Future[Long] = {
  val request = Get(uri)
  val responseFuture = Http().singleRequest(request)
  responseFuture.flatMap { response =>
    val source = response.entity.dataBytes
    source.runWith(FileIO.toFile(file))
  }
}
```

That was kind of okay but once I learnt more about pure Akka Streams I wanted to try and use the [Flow-Based Variant](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.2/scala/http/client-side/request-level.html#Flow-Based_Variant) to create a stream starting from a `Source[HttpRequest]`. At first this completely stumped me until I stumbled upon the `flatMapConcat` flow transformation. This ended up a little more verbose:

```
def responseOrFail[T](in: (Try[HttpResponse], T)): (HttpResponse, T) = in match {
  case (responseTry, context) => (responseTry.get, context)
}

def responseToByteSource[T](in: (HttpResponse, T)): Source[ByteString, Any] = in match {
  case (response, _) => response.entity.dataBytes
}

def downloadViaFlow(uri: Uri, file: File): Future[Long] = {
  val request = Get(uri)
  val source = Source.single((request, ()))
  val requestResponseFlow = Http().superPool[Unit]()
  source.
    via(requestResponseFlow).
    map(responseOrFail).
    flatMapConcat(responseToByteSource).
    runWith(FileIO.toFile(file))
}
```

Then I wanted to get a little tricky and use the `Content-Disposition` header.

Going back to the Future-Based Variant:

```
def destinationFile(downloadDir: File, response: HttpResponse): File = {
  val fileName = response.header[ContentDisposition].get.value
  val file = new File(downloadDir, fileName)
  file.createNewFile()
  file
}

def downloadViaFutures2(uri: Uri, downloadDir: File): Future[Long] = {
  val request = Get(uri)
  val responseFuture = Http().singleRequest(request)
  responseFuture.flatMap { response =>
    val file = destinationFile(downloadDir, response)
    val source = response.entity.dataBytes
    source.runWith(FileIO.toFile(file))
  }
}
```

But now I have no idea how to do this with the Future-Based Variant. This is as far as I got:

```
def responseToByteSourceWithDest[T](in: (HttpResponse, T), downloadDir: File): Source[(ByteString, File), Any] = in match {
  case (response, _) =>
    val source = responseToByteSource(in)
    val file = destinationFile(downloadDir, response)
    source.map((_, file))
}

def downloadViaFlow2(uri: Uri, downloadDir: File): Future[Long] = {
  val request = Get(uri)
  val source = Source.single((request, ()))
  val requestResponseFlow = Http().superPool[Unit]()
  val sourceWithDest: Source[(ByteString, File), Unit] = source.
    via(requestResponseFlow).
    map(responseOrFail).
    flatMapConcat(responseToByteSourceWithDest(_, downloadDir))
  sourceWithDest.runWith(???)
}
```

So now I have a `Source` that will emit one or more `(ByteString, File)` elements for each `File` (I say each `File` since there is no reason the original `Source` has to be a single `HttpRequest`).

Is there anyway to take these and route them to a dynamic `Sink`?

I'm thinking something like `flatMapConcat`, such as:

```
def runWithMap[T, Mat2](f: T => Graph[SinkShape[Out], Mat2])(implicit materializer: Materializer): Mat2 = ???
```

So that I could complete `downloadViaFlow2` with:

```
def destToSink(destination: File): Sink[(ByteString, File), Future[Long]] = {
  val sink = FileIO.toFile(destination, true)
  Flow[(ByteString, File)].map(_._1).toMat(sink)(Keep.right)
}
sourceWithDest.runWithMap {
  case (_, file) => destToSink(file)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution does not require a flatMapConcat.  If you don't need any return values from the file writing then you can use [`Sink.foreach`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.2/?_ga=1.233315486.129608303.1419543038#akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink$):

```
def writeFile(downloadDir : File)(httpResponse : HttpResponse) : Future[Long] = {
  val file = destinationFile(downloadDir, httpResponse)
  httpResponse.entity.dataBytes.runWith(FileIO.toFile(file))
}

def downloadViaFlow2(uri: Uri, downloadDir: File) : Future[Unit] = {
  val request = HttpRequest(uri=uri)
  val source = Source.single((request, ()))
  val requestResponseFlow = Http().superPool[Unit]()

  source.via(requestResponseFlow)
        .map(responseOrFail)
        .map(_._1)
        .runWith(Sink.foreach(writeFile(downloadDir)))
}
```

Note that the `Sink.foreach` creates `Futures` from the `writeFile` function.  Therefore there's not much back-pressure involved.  The writeFile could be slowed down by the hard drive but the stream would keep generating Futures.  To control this you can use [`Flow.mapAsyncUnordered`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.2/?_ga=1.233315486.129608303.1419543038#akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow) (or `Flow.mapAsync`) :

```
val parallelism = 10

source.via(requestResponseFlow)
      .map(responseOrFail)
      .map(_._1)
      .mapAsyncUnordered(parallelism)(writeFile(downloadDir))
      .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

If you want to accumulate the Long values for a total count you need to combine  with a `Sink.fold`:

```
source.via(requestResponseFlow)
      .map(responseOrFail)
      .map(_._1)
      .mapAsyncUnordered(parallelism)(writeFile(downloadDir))
      .runWith(Sink.fold(0L)(_ + _))
```

The fold will keep a running sum and emit the final value when the source of requests has dried up.

Comment: Hmm I was hoping there was a better way than this. I'm not too sure that this will actually work correctly either. `writeFile` will return as soon as the FileIO stream has been materialised. If the response is chunked then it needs to be written to the file in order. Similar problem with using the `mapAsync`. The `append` parameter would need to be set too. Also it seems like any errors writing to the file would not cause the outer stream to receive an error signal.

Comment: @Steiny Breaking up my answer to your multiple comments: (a) correct, write file returns with a Future immediately but the mapAsync handles this (b) there's no solution that can correct the chunkedsource nor was this part of the original question/requirements (c) append is only necessary if writing to the same file (d) forcing the outer stream to fail on any file write fail was not part of the original question.  You asked "Is there anyway to take these and route them to a dynamic Sink?", my response answers **that** question.  I wrote my response in the context of your example code...

Comment: and what happens when you get a 404?!  I'm sick of examples that leave out a major code path - that's why we use scala, to prevent that kind of crap coding!

Comment: @PlexQ I did not alter the logic of the original question which is where handling 404 would occur.  I was exclusively answering the question "Is there anyway to take these and route them to a dynamic Sink?"  If you want to ask a new question I would be happy to take a look.  Also, please refer to the updated code of conduct regarding friendly and unfriendly methods of communication: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Answer (score 2):

Using the play Web Services client injected in ws, remmebering to import scala.concurrent.duration._:

```
def downloadFromUrl(url: String)(ws: WSClient): Future[Try[File]] = {
  val file = File.createTempFile("my-prefix", new File("/tmp"))
  file.deleteOnExit()

  val futureResponse: Future[WSResponse] =
    ws.url(url).withMethod("GET").withRequestTimeout(5 minutes).stream()

  futureResponse.flatMap { res =>
    res.status match {
      case 200 =>
        val outputStream = java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(file.toPath)

        val sink = Sink.foreach[ByteString] { bytes => outputStream.write(bytes.toArray) }

        res.bodyAsSource.runWith(sink).andThen {
          case result =>
            outputStream.close()
            result.get
        } map (_ => Success(file))
      case other => Future(Failure[File](new Exception("HTTP Failure, response code " + other + " : " + res.statusText)))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed!